# How to insert a line from MemoList2 to the top of MemoList1

Tags: delphi

I have two string lists declared:

```
Memolist1,Memolist2:TStringList;
```

`MemoList2` has one line

`MemoList1` has many lines

How to insert a line from `MemoList2` to the top of `MemoList1`?

Comment: What's the problem for a man who knows word `insert`?  `MemoList1.Insert(0, MemoList2[0]);` Note that bold an capital letters used in the questions look weird

Comment: thank you man .. i am new on stackoverflow.com and i'm sorry about that bold and capital letters used in the questions .... thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, take [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a brief intro on Stack Overflow, and then read [**Asking**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). I edited your question to improve grammar and spelling. Next time you are in the editor take your time to look at the help in the editor for code formatting. Also, since your question is general for all Delphi versions, I removed the superfluous tags. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to insert Line From MemoList2 To Top Lines Of MemoList1

Translate your query literally into Delphi language

```
if MemoList2.Count > 0 then //check that list contains at least one line
    MemoList1.Insert(0, MemoList2[0]);
```